# Show Dialog on MenuItem click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to have a Dialog component pop up when you click on a MenuItem in a Material-UI Menu? I have a header component that returns the below JSX:

```
return (
<AppBar
  iconElementLeft={<a href='/'><Avatar src="/static/images/favicon.ico" style={{ marginTop:4 }} /></a>}
  title= {
          <div>
            {"Application"}
            {displaySearch?<div style={{display:'inline-block', marginLeft:20, width:500}}><Search location={location}/></div>:null}
            <div style={{float:'right'}}>
              {logoUri ? <img src={logoUri} style={{ height:40, verticalAlign:'middle',borderRadius:3,overflow:'hidden'}} /> : null}
            </div>
          </div>
  }
  iconElementRight={
      <IconMenu
        iconButtonElement={
          <IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>
        }
        targetOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top' }}
        anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top' }}
        >
        {
          menuItems.map(
            menuItem => <MenuItem containerElement={<Link to={menuItem.uri} />} primaryText={menuItem.primaryText} key={menuItem.key} />)
        }
        <MenuItem href='#' primaryText={'about'} onTouchTap={()=>{}}  />
        <MenuItem href='/auth/logout' primaryText={'logout'}  />
      </IconMenu>
  }
  <Dialog ref="dialog" title="version 1.0" open={true}>
    Version: {version}
  </Dialog>
  />
)
```

I'm just trying to wire up the 'about' menu item to the dialog that pops up and displays the version information that I pass along to the page, but once I include the Dialog in the IconMenu, if you click on the IconMenu, nothing shows and I get an error:

```
"Menu.js:222 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'opacity' of undefined".
```

If I remove the Dialog component, my MenuItem works as intended. I'm not sure how exactly I can wire up a MenuItem to a Dialog. Is it possible to have a MenuItem trigger a Dialog component in Material-UI?

Comment: there is  `</DialogExampleSimple>` in material-ui docs. put it into menu item like this `</MenuItem chidren={</DialogExampleSimple>}`

Comment: Hard to read your example code, I think your Dialog is in a wrong place (as AppBar props?) in your example. Basically you should use MenuItem Click to control visibility of your dialog. When somebody clicks About change `this.state.open` to `true`. You should have somewhere in render Dialog component that takes this `this.state.open` and you shouldn't keep Dialog component inside IconMenu

Answer (score 0):

You could create the dialog as a menu item:

```
import MenuDialog from './MenuDialog';
```

Then

```
<IconMenu
    ...
    <MenuDialog />
    ...
</IconMenu>
```

And now in a seperate MenuDialog.js file, as a component which is imported above

```
render(){
const actions = [<FlatButton 
    label="Close"
    primary={true} 
    onClick={this.handleClose} />
]
    return(
       <div> 
<MenuItem onClick={this.handleOpen}>Press for dialog </MenuItem>
<Dialog
    title={Dialog name}
    actions={actions}
    modal={false}
    open={this.state.open}
    onRequestClose={this.handleClose}> Dialog writing
</Dialog>
</div>
)
}
```